# Is there a way to instantiate all the c++ template sizes at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-cli

The c++/cli template below is working, but it seems like there ought to be a way to generalize the template further or add a helper that can create the template instances at compile time.

Was thinking something like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence might work, but need some assistance with the helper / implementer function.

Simplified main to demonstrate the desired syntax vs what is currently used:

```
int main(array<String^>^ args) {

    // the actual number of possible char lengths is sparse (generally)
    // but the API allows for 1-1024
    List<int>^ varList = gcnew List<int>();
    varList->Add(40);
    varList->Add(80);
    varList->Add(128);

    SortedList<int, List<String^>^>^ allStrings = gcnew SortedList<int, List<String^>^>();

    // want something like this, but the compiler complains that 
    // the template is invalid expectes compile-time constant expressions
    for each(int key in varList) {
        allStrings->Add(key, UpdateTest<key>());
    }

    // this works, but has 1024 lines of case N:
    for each(int key in varList) {
        switch (key) {
        case 1: allStrings->Add(key, UpdateTest<1>());
        case 2: allStrings->Add(key, UpdateTest<2>());
        case 3: allStrings->Add(key, UpdateTest<3>());
            //... all 1024 possible char[N] sizes...
        case 1024: allStrings->Add(key, UpdateTest<1024>());
        }
    }
}
```

Template works with the 1024 switch case N: calls.  Is there a way to have a helper / implementer instantiate all 1024 without the cases?

```
template <std::size_t N> List<String^>^ APIwrapper::UpdateTest() {
    typedef char CHARX[N];  // N valid for 1 to 1024
    CHARX vals[MAXFIELDS];

    // NATIVE C++ VendorAPI(short, void*) vals is the address of the word aligned destination data
    int count = VendorAPI(N, &vals); 

    List<String^>^ retList = gcnew List<String^>();

    for (int c = 0; c < count; c++) {
        CHARX temp;
        strncpy(temp, vals[c], N);  // \0 terminated char arrays
        String^ x = gcnew String(temp);
        retList->Add(x->Substring(0, N)->Trim());
    }
    return retList;
}
```

Comment: What could be the point of instantiating all those templates?

Comment: There is no way to know apriori which char[N] sizes are in the vendor's data.  Any or all of the 1-1024 may be there.  And the 1024 switch cases are de facto instantiating them.

Comment: I do not see how the bounty (knowing "if instantiating all of the templates would be possible") is useful. Even if it could be done, why would you want to instantiate 1024 specialized functions instead of one generalized function that could handle all 1024 cases (and probably more)? Isn't this like trying to instantiate `template <int N> int Add(int X) { return X + N; }` for `N` equal to 1 through 1024 because you don't like adding two variables together? What's so special about your scenario that warrants bloating the executable size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following answer works for c++14, I don't know if it's compatible with cli.

You can use templates to generate a `std::array` of function pointers:

```
using UpdateTestPtr = decltype(&UpdateTest<0>);

// Struct used to generate the array's content.
template<typename Sequence>
struct UpdateTestArrayImpl;

// Specialization used to get the values in the integer sequence.
template<std::size_t... indices>
struct UpdateTestArrayImpl<std::integer_sequence<std::size_t,indices...>> {
    static constexpr std::array<UpdateTestPtr,sizeof...(indices)> value{UpdateTest<indices>...};
};

// Factorise sequence creation
template<std::size_t N>
using UpdateTestArray = UpdateTestArrayImpl<std::make_index_sequence<N>>;

static constexpr std::size_t N = 512;
// The array is needed at runtime. Create a normal (not constexpr) instance.
static std::array<UpdateTestPtr,N> functionArray = UpdateTestArray<N>::value;
```

And turn the `switch/case` into an array lookup:

```
for each(int key in varList) {
    allStrings->Add(key, functionArray[key]());
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aET8sXRVLaJNbSnA)

Some compilers might produce a "template instantiation depth" error, depending on how `make_integer_sequence` is implemented. The max limit of recursion depth can normally be increased with compiler options.

Comment: Version of the compiler suite is "old", `std::make_index_sequence` can be implemented with logarithm complexity (instead of linear) (and compiler might even provide intrinsic to do it in constant time ;-)).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the input. Indeed more recent versions of gcc/clang have no problems with longer sequences. I changed the live demo link to use more recent compilers.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do this with templates.

You're using templates to turn a single large block of memory (`CHARX vals[MAXFIELDS];`) into lots of individual strings. Instead, do that yourself.

```
List<String^>^ APIwrapper::UpdateTest(size_t size)
{
    char* vals = new char[size * MAXFIELDS];

    // NATIVE C++ VendorAPI(short, void*) vals is the address of the word aligned destination data
    int count = VendorAPI(size, vals); 

    List<String^>^ retList = gcnew List<String^>();

    char temp[1025]; // max size + 1.
    for (int c = 0; c < count; c++)
    {
        // Instead of relying on the compiler to know that [1] should be 10 bytes in, 
        // [2] should be 20 bytes in, etc, do that yourself.
        strncpy(temp, &vals[size * c], size);
        temp[size] = '\0'; // safety
        String^ x = gcnew String(temp);
        retList->Add(x->Trim());
    }

    delete [] vals;

    return retList;
}
```

Now, having said that: This is an unusual API. Effectively, you're passing a block of memory, and a *stride* for the placement of each string. That's somewhat strange, but also only some data can be retrieved with each stride value??? That's very strange. I would check if the vendor's API will still respond properly if 1024 is always used as the stride.

Comment: The VendorAPI was simplified for the example.  It is simply passing a block of memory and actually works for other data types, long, short, float, double, custom time structure, other custom structures & etc.  It will not work with a char[1024] used for other char[N] sizes.  That's why a template approach was being attempted.  The answer (edited) is a good solution that solves my stated problem while not answering my real question.